# Exception outside of destructor

Tags: c++

Here is my destructor :

```
CDBColumnInfo::~CDBColumnInfo()
{
    m_rowIndexDataMap.clear();
    m_colNameList.clear();
    m_colNameMap.clear();
}
```

Aafter go out of close bracket, it throw exception in function

```
_CRT_SECURITYCRITICAL_ATTRIBUTE
void __CRTDECL operator delete(void* const block) noexcept
{
    #ifdef _DEBUG
    _free_dbg(block, _UNKNOWN_BLOCK);
    #else
    free(block);
    #endif
}
```

When I debug, I check in disassembly code it show that exception in this line :

```
00007FFEA4AB8660  call        std::map<int,_bstr_t,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<int const ,_bstr_t> > >::~map<int,_bstr_t,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<int const ,_bstr_t> > > (07FFEA4A43E7Ch)
```

I dont known what exactly happend but in my program define a map like this :

//Code updated

```
std::map<int, _bstr_t> m_rowIndexDataMap; //class variable

HRESULT CDBColumnInfo::AddData() 
{
    CComPtr<CDBColumnInfo> spResult = new CDBColumnInfo();
    map<int,_bstr_t> recordMap ;
    _bstr_t record;
    for (int rownum = 0; rownum < num_rows; ++rownum){
        const int num_cols = PQnfields(res);
        record = "";
        for (int colnum = 0; colnum < num_cols; ++colnum) {
            if (PQgetisnull(res, rownum, colnum) == 0) {
                char* data = PQgetvalue(res, rownum, colnum);
                record = record + data;
            }
            else {
                record = record + L"<NULL>";
            }

            if (colnum + 1 < num_cols) {
                record = record + "#";
            }
        }
    recordMap[rownum] = record;             
    }

    spResult->SetMap(recordMap);
    ...
    ...

}
STDMETHODIMP CDBColumnInfo::SetMap (std::map<int, _bstr_t> dataMap)
{
    CComSingleLock lock (m_critSec);
    m_rowIndexDataMap = dataMap;
    return S_OK;
}

STDMETHODIMP CDBColumnInfo::GetMap (DBrowIndexToDataMap& dataMap)
{
    CComSingleLock lock (m_critSec);
    dataMap = m_rowIndexDataMap;
    return S_OK;
}


CDBColumnInfo::~CDBColumnInfo()
{
    m_rowIndexDataMap.clear();
    m_colNameList.clear();
    m_colNameMap.clear();
}
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Please, note, that there might be more destructor code than what you wrote into the code. The compiler will add its own destructor code as well. I'm afraid you have somewhere Undefined Behavior in your code (but not necessarily in the exposed destructor) which e.g. causes a double free (or there is some other heap corruption).

Comment: yes, sorry. My typo

Comment: Deffo going to need a MCVE on this one mate

Comment: `STDMETHODIMP CDBColumnInfo::SetMap (std::map<int, _bstr_t> dataMap)` -- Is this function by chance one that can be called across module boundaries?  Also, why would you need to call `clear()` in the destructor?  A `std::map` will automatically clean itself up on destruction of the object it is a member of.

Comment: You can perhaps loop though all the entries in the map before clearing it to find the  `int, _bstr_t` pair causing the problem.  One of the `_bstr_t`s may have been `Attach`ed to a  `BSTR` (that was later `SysFreeString`ed) instead of `Assign`ed to it. That could cause this I believe. Edit: perhaps I misinterpreted the manual. `Attach` seems capable of doing a silent `Assign` too... Not sure.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I was updated code to show how data was put into map, please help me

Comment: Hard do say but it should be fairly easy to make a small [mcve] out of the parts you've shown to make it easy for others to help. Btw, you are mixing adding both `char*` strings (returned by `PQgetvalue`) and `wchar_t*` strings (`L"<NULL>"`) to the same `record`. I'm not sure how that'll be handled by `_bstr_t`. What happens if you remove the `L`?

Comment: @Ryo `CComPtr<CDBColumnInfo> spResult = new CDBColumnInfo();` -- This is a local variable.  Where / how is this referred to outside of the `AddData` function?  I don't see anywhere this is used.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first "~" from your destructor. It should be

```
CDBColumnInfo::~CDBColumnInfo()
{
    m_rowIndexDataMap.clear();
    m_colNameList.clear();
    m_colNameMap.clear();
}
```

Comment: Yes, sorry. My Typo

Comment: if the question is unclear (eg due to a missing mcve) it is often better to ask for clarification first. This appears to be just a typo here that is not present in OPs real code

Comment: One thing that can happen incorrectly with eyes destructors is when they are not defined as virtual but the class has inheritance hierarchy destroyed dynamically.