# Map clear throw exception

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a map and process to add data like this :

```
interface CDBColumnInfo
      : public IDBColumnInfo
    {
    public:
        CDBColumnInfo();
        ~CDBColumnInfo();
   private:
    map<int,_bstr_t> m_rowIndexDataMap ;

   HRESULT AddDataToMap(){
    _bstr_t record;
    for (int rownum = 0; rownum < num_rows; ++rownum){
        const int num_cols = PQnfields(res);
        record = "";
        for (int colnum = 0; colnum < num_cols; ++colnum) {
            if (PQgetisnull(res, rownum, colnum) == 0) {
                _bstr_t data = PQgetvalue(res, rownum, colnum);
                record = record + data;
            }
            else {
                record = record + "<NULL>";
            }

            if (colnum + 1 < num_cols) {
                record = record + "#";
            }
        }
        m_rowIndexDataMap[rownum] = record;             
    }

  }
```

After program complete, I clear map in destructor by :

```
CDBColumnInfo::~CDBColumnInfo() {
 m_rowIndexDataMap.clear();
}
```

The I got exception when destructor completed:

```
File: minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\heap\debug_heap.cpp
Line: 904

Expression: _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(block)
```

I tried to loop map and manually and determine exception happened in 1st element :

```
for (auto it = m_rowIndexDataMap.cbegin(); it != m_rowIndexDataMap.cend() ;)
{       

    it = m_rowIndexDataMap.erase(it);    //  exception happened at first element

}
m_rowIndexDataMap.clear();
```

What wrong with data in map?

Comment: which c++ compiler? What platform?

Comment: `interface` is not standard C++. Is this one of those weird Microsoft "enhancements"?

Comment: Maybe your library is buggy... or you have a memory corruption somewhere else! Good hunt! ;)

Comment: You don't need to explicitly `clear` a `map` when it's going to be destroyed.

Comment: @molbdnilo I known that, but I got exception in program, after few days of debug, I doubt that error happened in map destroy , so I tried to manually it

Comment: I suspect that the problem is somewhere else. It can take quite a while after memory corruption for any symptoms to manifest themselves.

Comment: @Ryo *after few days of debug* -- Time to hire a consultant.  It shouldn't have taken days of debugging.  If it did, then why do you think it would take us minutes to figure this out, with that little bit of code you posted?

Comment: As was suggested [when you started this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56075372/exception-outside-of-destructor), make a [mcve].

Comment: We also have no idea if the object `CDBColumnInfo` (`this`) is even valid.  If it is not valid, then any operation you perform using it is invalid, even something as simple as an `erase()` call.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Could you tell me which part not clear? My program is so complex than this. I tried to make it simple as much as possible. This also help me how to make good question.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm newbie in C++ so I think my problem is big with me but maybe not with you

Comment: @Ryo It's not possible to copy your code into a blank VS project and compile it. It also uses non-standard classes that are probably not needed to reproduce the problem. If you make a small program containing a `std::map<int,_bstr_t>` and then populate the map without using `PQgetvalue` etc., are you then able to reproduce the error?

Comment: We cannot tell from the code you have what the issue is.  I would suggest you get rid of the the `_bstr_t` as a value in the map, and just store "regular" string types such as `std::string` or `std::wstring`.  Use `_bstr_t` only as input or output, not as a map value.

Comment: You probably cause heap corruption elsewhere in the program and it happens to show up when you free the `_bstr_t` strings

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for your suggestion. I changed all to std::string then the exception has gone

Answer (score 1):

The error you recieved:

```
File: minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\heap\debug_heap.cpp Line: 904

Expression: _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(block)
```

Is not neccesarily caused by the 'actual' code or call stack, but most likely somewhere else in your code since it can be caused by a routine check of the heap:

> Heap-Check Frequency Macros
>
> You can specify how often the C run-time library performs validation
>   of the debug heap (_CrtCheckMemory) based on the number of calls to
>   malloc, realloc, free, and _msize.

For more info see, [_CrtSetDbgFlag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/crtsetdbgflag?view=vs-2019)